# excluding .svn .git files from find+xargs+grep pipe

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I have an Emacs function `(fgf "thing")` that creates a subprocess that looks like this:

```
find .  \( -type f -a \! -regex '\.(svn|git)' \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nH -e 'thing'
```

Basically I don't want `grep` to look at *any* of the `.git` or `.svn` files.  How can I do that?

Comment: What's not working with the command you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type d '(' -name .svn -o -name .git ')' -prune -o -type f -exec grep -nH -e 'thing' {} +
```

Using `-prune` to avoid recursing into `.svn` and `.git` directories is better than using a regex. Also `-exec` is preferable to `-print0 | xargs -0`.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't quite work.  Got a list of directories and output that said grep: <dirname>: Is a directory

Comment: With your `-type f` edit it worked perfectly.  Thank you very much!